# Any way to change dark Netbeans IDE theme?

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I'm currently (trying) to setup a dev environment in Linux (Ubuntu) and have opted to use Netbeans PHP as my IDE.

The main toolbar at the top is too dark to read the menu item text (unless I click to bring up the dropdown, which won't really do). Is there any way I can fix this? Do I have to use a different Ubuntu theme, or can Netbeans be changed?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this?

http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/themes/themes.html

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the link. This page (http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/netbeans-ide-look-feel-under-ubuntu-12-04/) was a quicker fix for me in the end.

Comment: Great! glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an old question I know.

I had a similar problem as well. + ftp problems.
Using an ugly laf wasn't the answer I was looking for.

I'm using **openjdk-7-jre** now to run Netbeans.
It fixed the problem with the dark menu as well as a problem with brocken ftp-connections from netbeans.

Using: Netbeans 7.3 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was also having freezing issues with Netbeans 7.3 and Ubuntu 13. Using openjdk-7-jre fixed all of my problems.

Answer (score 9):

There are number of bug reports on the issue you're experiencing. You can however change the look and feel. As of writing, the following are available:

- **Windows** - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
- **Metal** - javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
- **GTK** - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
- **Nimbus** - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
- **Aqua** - apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel

* ***`<laf_name>`*** - `<laf_class>`

### Changing the Look and Feel

Use the `--laf <laf_class|laf_name>` start-up option.

1. Edit the configuration file:

   `sudo vi /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/etc/netbeans.conf`
2. Add custom look and feel by adding the `--laf <laf_class|laf_name>` option to the `netbeans_default_options` variable.

e.g. If you want **Nimbus**:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m 
    -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true 
    -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true 
    --laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
```

or by *name* e.g. if you want **Metal**:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m 
    -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true 
    -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true 
    --laf Metal"
```

### Test Look and Feel & other options by running from Terminal

Running from the terminal is easy:

```
$ /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/bin/netbeans
```

Run with **Metal** look and feel:

```
$ /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/bin/netbeans --laf Metal
```

Run with **GTK** look and feel:

```
$ /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/bin/netbeans --laf GTK
```

### Extra Credit

Run from terminal in background job; append **&**

```
$ /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/bin/netbeans --laf Metal &
```

Create a symlink to bypass specifying the path:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/netbeans-{VERSION}/bin/netbeans ~/bin/netbeans
# now you can run without specifying the path
$ netbeans
# run in background job
$ netbeans &
# run with Metal laf in background job
$ netbeans --laf Metal &
```

### Resources

- [How do I make my custom startup parameters permanent?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf)
- [Look and Feels in NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels)
- [Can I run NetBeans with a custom Look and Feel (laf)?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomLaf)

Comment: any way to load external theme ?

Comment: Well, the look-and-feel option, `--laf`, accepts either a *class* or an *alias*: `--laf <laf_class|laf_name>`. My best guess would be that: if you use the class name and that class is available to netbeans, it will be loaded. No? How to ensure the class is available to netbeans? That I don't know.

Comment: thank you.
I also ignore how to make an external class available to netbeans ... 
... maybe addind something like this to the config should solve (this is for javahl library ... ): -J-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions on this [page](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/netbeans-ide-look-feel-under-ubuntu-12-04/) fixed my problem in the end.